# It wont set the session?

Tags: php, session

I have this php login system, I had it working great on localhost, I bought a webhotel and now it doesn't work no longer, and i can't find where it goes wrong.

I get no errors.

The login page is in index.php, and when you sign in, and if everythings ok (no errors/wrong pw etc.) then you will be redirected to home.php.

This is not the case. When I log in, it just refreshes the index.php and outputs this at top:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (httpd.www/oBz/index.php:2) in httpd.www/oBz/index.php on line 221

on line 221 there's:
         header("Location: home.php");

ok, so i went to home.php manually by enter in the address. Now in home.php I have this at top:

```
include 'dbc.php';
page_protect();
echo "HELLO WORLD";
```

page_protect checks if there's any sessions set or cookie(remember me), but if something has been set you will see the content "HELLO WORLD" else you wont.

But right now when i enter home.php I just receive this:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at httpd.www/oBz/dbc.php:29) in httpd.www/oBz/dbc.php on line 69
>   Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at httpd.www/oBz/dbc.php:29) in httpd.www/oBz/dbc.php on line 69
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at httpd.www/oBz/dbc.php:29) in httpd.www/oBz/dbc.php on line 117

Line 69 theres `session_start()`, and it's the first line in the function `page_protect()`;

line 117 theres `header("Location: index.php")` and is there to redirect if you are not logged in(session set/cookie set)

Hope i provided information enough, if not just comment what you need, and i'll try my best to provide it to you..

Thank you

Update:

**Here is dbc.php: http://phpbin.net/x/999009567**

**index.php where you log in and where the session sets http://phpbin.net/x/1564167411

**UPDATE:
 I now solved the header warning/errors but that was not the solution for the session issue!

**UPDATE:
phpbin.net/x/25857430 the updated dbc.php, all the html that was in the dbc.php previously is in a new file top.php. I include the top.php file AFTER the doLogin function section in index.php, so there doesnt get any errors with the headers..

***UPDATE: The problem is somewhere here: http://phpbin.net/x/557713701 thats why its redirecting me  to index.php all the time

Comment: http://phpbin.net/x/999009567

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already sent output to the browser with all that HTML that exists before your first bit of PHP.

You need to rearrange the code, so that anything which needs to send headers happens before any HTML is sent to the browser.

So:

```
<?php
session_start();

?>
<html>
<head>
...
```

The simplest answer may be to move all of that HTML after the PHP code.  There's a `session_regenerate_id()` call in there and another `session_start()` in the `logout` function.

For that matter, why do have any HTML in this file anyway?  Beyond the session functions, I spotted at least 2 `header()` calls.

**Update:**

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])){
    /* we double check cookie expiry time against stored in database */

// I snipped a bunch of code, to point out what's going on here

  } else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
    }
```

So, if the cookie values don't exist, what do you suppose happens here?

Comment: I did what you said rearranged the code, moved all html in another file (top.php) so i just call that for the html stuff, this cleaned up the warnings but didnt fix the solution.

Comment: @karem Theres's a lot of reasons why it may redirect to index.php.  Find every `header("Location: index.php");` call and debug the code before that.  Maybe cookies aren't being sent or set correctly, for example.

Comment: @George Marian cookies aren't being set if you havent checked "remember", but i think you ment sessions. I have 2 header location index.php, one inside logout function, and one if either cookie or session is set

Comment: @George if you see the line above that, you will find:
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ) 
{
So The code you posted in your updated answer will start if session isnt setted

Comment: @karem Only if the cookies are set.

Comment: @george i found something interesting.. I changed every index.php to indexR.php which doesnt exist and when i log on it trys to go to indexR.php. And one after one i found out which header it was, and now i think i know what code part that needs to be fixed, heres PHPbin: http://phpbin.net/x/557713701

Comment: @karem That's exactly the bit of code I'm trying to point out.  One of the problems is that this code covers quite a number of lines, which may be unavoidable.  Another problem, is that your indentation isn't consistent, making it more difficult to identify the blocks of code.  I actually copied your code into an editor, so I could use it's brace matching to identify the blocks of code.  Wihtout even looking any deeper into the code, I can tell you that `if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])){` requires that the cookies be set, in order to set any session variables.

Comment: @George Ok, from what i can understand of the code the line if isset cookie is above if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !isset($_SESSION['user_name']) )  which means if there isnt any active session set it will check for the cookies, do you understand? And even so, if we stop here, if it starts to check for cookies then somethings wrong because the session should be setted when you log in? comfusing, but funny that it all works on my localhost

Comment: FINALLY A BIG THANK YOU! Why i commented it out, or how it got commented out, I cant remember, but a big thank you! Appreciate...really!!

Comment: @karem You're quite welcome.  It probably happened when you were trying to debug the header issue.  It happens to us all, at one point or another.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at the wrong bits of the error message. The part you're looking at is where it tries to send the headers (ie: where it realizes something is wrong). The relevant part, however, is the part where it began producing output. For the first error, it says the output was already started at index.php, line 2. You probably have whitespace in front of your opening `<?php` tag. I'd check that first...

Comment: please check the dbc.php i have uploaded. No i do not have a whitespace infront of the <?php.

Comment: @Karem well it may be after ?> tag. Why can't you check the line 29 yourself?

Comment: You have output before the tag. session_start() must be called before any output. The reason why it probably worked on your localhost server was you had output buffering turned on (would be my guess). A simple `<?php session_start(); ?>`  before the `<html>` should solve the issue (and of course remove it from that function).

Comment: @premiso i just checked my wampserver setting, and I do have output buffering turned on, so you might be right. I made session_start at the top of dbc.php and removed any other session_start(); in files, but still something is occuring the problem, because it wont login..

Comment: @karem `$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])` Where is $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']  being set?

Comment: @Karem Infact you have ~25 lines of output infront of `<?php` in dbc.php

Comment: @Mike B @George Marian @premiso I have solved the headers errors, and rearranged the code but still the session issue wont work

Comment: @Karem You're going to need to provide us with the updated code.

Comment: @George Marian http://phpbin.net/x/25857430 dbc.php, all the html that was in the dbc.php previously is in a new file top.php. I include the top.php file AFTER the doLogin function section in index.php, so there doesnt get any errors with the headers..

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, when i log in on index.php, nothing happends, 1) i dont get redirected 2) and even when i try to enter home.php manually now, i get redirected back to index.php, which means sessions are not set.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess :

Did you issue

```
die();
```

After `header("Location: home.php");`

???

You might just forget to close the output so that it prints out the rest of the page regardless of this redirection.

Also, please confirm that the encoding is good, should be UTF-8? Sometimes I got it wrong myself :(

Okay, updated answer:

```
266 header("Location: index.php");

303 header("Location: home.php");

340 header("Location: home.php");
```

You didn't issue Die() after these three lines. So this might be a risk :)

Comment: I used exit(); i tried die(); i still have headers errors, but I just found out that is not the session issue problem.

Comment: i've issued die(); now, still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

And line 29 of dbc.php is echoing, or printing, or generating some output to the browser....  so what's the code in dbc.php around that line?

Likewise line 2 of index.php